# How to do simple processing job (batch) in Azure in the most efficient and cheap manner

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-functions, azure-batch

I will be receiving around 300 .csv files (small files in KB, no cleansing required) every month, which will need processing (not major processing) to find interesting facts in a report (using Python code) and sending the output reports to a cloud storage and email to specific email address. The challenge is to design the architect in the most efficient and cost-effective way. I have a couple of options, but I would like some suggestions on how to do it using AZURE.

One option is to use Azure blob storage trigger and Azure function and then store the results in output zone of the blob storage. One catch is that Azure function can run up to 15 minutes I think.

The option looks cheaper, however since the nature of job is batch I am wondering if there is any other cheaper and efficient option.

Comment: Did you happen to check Azure batch as an service - https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/batch/batch-technical-overview.md

Comment: Azure Functions would be easy to set up and run, As the cost of consumption based plan is very less

Comment: FYI this question is off-topic as written: you're asking for recommendations and opinions (including pricing-related answers). And you haven't shown any specific work of your own. Please read [ask] as well as how to create a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of Batch Service to perform your batch jobs in a Python based batch processing like below:-

I have referred this Python batch service [quickstart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/quick-run-python):-

Cloned the same application, Created one Batch service and edited config.py with the values below:-

```py
BATCH_ACCOUNT_NAME = 'siliconbatch1'  
BATCH_ACCOUNT_KEY = 'CiI4HtsUw9GZ5YEc1BnoPmjb8ttwuP6GArO0wvltE+uoimclEwZnU9LJMjqnWCR4Ja9cPRVDHG7X+ABalNG3Iw=='  
BATCH_ACCOUNT_URL = 'https://siliconbatch1.australiaeast.batch.azure.com'  
STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME = 'valleystrg129'
STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY = 'xxxxxxxDF+AStPI60+Q=='
STORAGE_ACCOUNT_DOMAIN = 'blob.core.windows.net'
```

[image]

**Output:-**

[image]

Blobs got uploaded to storage account with the batch job successfully like below:-

[image]

Another alternative as you suggested is to use Azure Functions Blob Trigger with input and output binding set to blob, Where the Blob To Blob trigger will copy blob from one blob to another in same or different storage account. Refer below steps to implement the same scenario:-

**My init.py:-**

```py
import logging

import azure.functions as func


def main(myblob: func.InputStream, outputBlob: func.Out[str]) -> None:
    logging.info(f"Python blob trigger function processed blob \n"
                 f"Name: {myblob.name}\n"
                 f"Blob Size: {myblob.length} bytes")
    
    clear_text = myblob.read().decode('utf-8')
    #logging.info("Clear text:%s'", clear_text)

    outputBlob.set(clear_text)
```

**function.json with input and output binding set to 2 different blobs, You can set this according to your requirement:-**

[image]

[image]

```json
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myblob",
      "type": "blobTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "testhubname-applease/{name}",
      "connection": "valleystrg129_STORAGE"
    },
    {
      "type": "blob",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "outputBlob",
      "path": "testhubname-leases/{rand-guid}",
      "connection": "valleystrg129_STORAGE"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Output:-**

[image]

Comment: You're answering a wide-open, opinion-based, recommendation-based question, where the OP showed no work of their own. This question doesn't answer any specific question; rather, it's a  custom blog post based on the OP's requirements. *Please don't do this.*  The OP literally provided zero code, no data, no errors.... *nothing* at all. Also, for future posts you make: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Hi @DavidMakogon Acknowledged. Attempted this question as the ask is related to 300+ csv files transformation and then a requirement to upload them in Azure Blob storage, As Azure batch service supports python and Azure Function Blob Trigger input and output bindings meets the Op's requirement. Thanks..

Comment: Yup I get it. But the issue is that Stack Overflow is for discrete Q&A, not for custom solutions to requirements someone publishes with no specific problem and no work of their own.

Comment: @SiddheshDesai Thank you for answering in detail. I checked the link you mentioned. While it is definitely a solution, I think it is feasible when one has a big job in which case the compute infrastructure can start up, do the job and shutdown again. In the case of small processing job, I think functions are still the winner economically.